# How to make a list of Months along with Year (for eg. January 2022, February 2022) from a given Date until current month in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, sorting, datetime, dart

I am trying to prepare a list of Months with Years, such as below:

```
monthYearList = ["December 2021", "January 2022", "February 2022"]
```

I have a date given, say:  `date = "2021-10-25"` .
Date Format is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Now how to prepare the data for all the Months along with Years from this given date until the current month in a List.

Expected Output: `monthYearList =  ["October 2021", "November 2021", "December 2021", "January 2022", "February 2022"]`

Such that it's in non-decreasing order as per month progression.

`"November 2021", "December 2021"` comes before `"January 2022"` only until the current month.

I am new to Flutter, and don't have much idea how to work with Dates in dart.

Comment: For the example in the question, why is October the first month in the list?

Comment: Sorry about that, edited it now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

```
List<String> getMonthsFromDayTillNow(String day) {
  // 2021-10-
  List<String> dateSplit = day.split("-");
  DateTime loopDateTime =
      DateTime(int.parse(dateSplit[0]), int.parse(dateSplit[1]), 28);
  DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.now();
  List<String> months = [];
  while (loopDateTime.isBefore(currentDateTime)) {
    months.add("${getMonth(loopDateTime.month)} ${loopDateTime.year}");
    loopDateTime = loopDateTime.add(Duration(days: 5));
    loopDateTime = DateTime(loopDateTime.year, loopDateTime.month, 28);
  }
  months.add("${getMonth(currentDateTime.month)} ${currentDateTime.year}");
  return months;
}

String getMonth(int monthNumber) {
  late String month;
  switch (monthNumber) {
    case 1:
      month = "January";
      break;
    case 2:
      month = "February";
      break;
    case 3:
      month = "March";
      break;
    case 4:
      month = "April";
      break;
    case 5:
      month = "May";
      break;
    case 6:
      month = "June";
      break;
    case 7:
      month = "July";
      break;
    case 8:
      month = "August";
      break;
    case 9:
      month = "September";
      break;
    case 10:
      month = "October";
      break;
    case 11:
      month = "November";
      break;
    case 12:
      month = "December";
      break;
  }
  return month;
}
```

Output:

```
void main() {
  print(getMonthsFromDayTillNow("2021-10-5")); //[October 2021, November 2021, December 2021, January 2022, February 2022]

}
```

Comment: Worked like charm, just as expected. Thanks a lot for your help sir.